# Using Datatable to format table, however, it will not work for all my tables only one

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatable

I have the following within the application.js and I've also tried putting it in prices.coffee.js

jQuery ->

```
$('#container').dataTable();
```

However, the following table will not format in the DataTable design:

```
<h2>Energy Prices</h2>

<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<table id ="container" class="display">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Elec</th>
    <th>Gas</th>
    <th>Biomass</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<% @usages.each do |usage| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= usage.price.usage_id %></td>
    <td><%= usage.month.strftime("%b %Y") %></td>
    <% usage.price.attributes.each do |k,v| %>
        <% if v.nil? %>
            <td>N/A</td>
        <% elsif k != "created_at" && k != "updated_at" && k != "month" && k != "id" && k != "usage_id" %>
            <td><%= v %></td>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_price_path(usage) %> </td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs [may only be used once per page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute). I imagine your issue is that you have multiple tables all using the same ID. Try using a `class` or `data-*` attribute instead.

```
<table class="container">
$('table.container').dataTable();
```

Or:

```
<table data-whatever="container">
$('table[data-whatever="container"]').dataTable();
```

Comment: Hi James thanks for the prompt reply. I changed it so that my two tables now are <table class = "container"> and also changed the application to $('table.container').dataTable(): and now none of them contain the DataTables format?